# How to configure axon server in pod for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, axon

I have 3 services which are axon, command and query. I am trying running them via Kubernetes. With docker-compose and swarm works perfectly. But somehow not working via K8s. 
Getting following error:

`Connecting to AxonServer node axonserver:8124 failed: UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host axonserver`
Below are my config files.

```
 `
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: StatefulSet
  metadata:
    name: axonserver
    labels:
      app: axonserver
  spec:
    serviceName: axonserver
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: axonserver
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: axonserver
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: axonserver
            image: axoniq/axonserver
            env:
            - name: AXONSERVER_HOSTNAME
             value: axonserver
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            ports:
            - name: grpc
              containerPort: 8124
              protocol: TCP
            - name: gui
              containerPort: 8024
              protocol: TCP
```

`

Here is command-service yaml contains service as well.

```
  apiVersion: 
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    name: command-service
    labels:
      name: peanuts
      app: axonserver
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: axonserver
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: celcin/command-svc
          name: command-service
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          restartPolicy: Always
        status: {}
   ---
   apiVersion: v1 
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: command-service
       labels:
         name: peanuts
         app: axonserver
   spec:
     ports:
     - name: "8081"
       port: 8081
       targetPort: 8080
     selector:
       labels:
         app: axonserver
```

`

Here is last service as query-service yml file

```
 ` apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     name: query-service
     labels:
       name: peanuts
       app: axonserver
   spec:
     replicas: 1
       template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: axonserver
       spec:
         containers:
         - image: celcin/query-svc
           name: query-service
           ports:
           - containerPort: 8080
         restartPolicy: Always
       ---
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: query-service
     labels:
       name: peanuts
       app: axonserver
   spec:
     ports:
     - name: "8082"
       port: 8082
       targetPort: 8080
     selector:
       labels:
         app: axonserver`
```

Comment: I assume that axon-deployment.yml file has something wrong but do not know how to solve it

Comment: You typically use docker-compose for local development because it can build and works only on a single docker engine. Docker stack and docker service commands require a Docker Swarm (configured by defaut) or Kubernetes cluster, and they are step towards production.

Docker Desktop comes with Kubernetes and the Compose controller built-in, and enabling it is as simple as ticking a box in the settings.

Now, you can use Docker Compose file and native Docker API for stacks to manage applications/services on local Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/idugalic/axon-scale-demo#deploy-docker-stack-to-kubernetes

Comment: If you prefer Kubernetes deployments YAML, you could investigate this docker-compose deployment and map it to Kubernetes YAML. I'm sure that there are some tools that can help you with this mapping : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/

Comment: i aimed to just run same app on kubernetes, also development purpose. thank you i m checking your example

Comment: @IvanDugalic i used that tools but with axon server is a bit complicate i guess

Comment: In that case Docker Stack & docker-compose are good (and fast) fit ;)

Comment: There is a section on Axon docs describing how to launch Axon Server (Community edition) on Kubernetes (with deployment/services YAML): https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/operations-guide/setting-up-axon-server/launch#starting-axon-server-in-kubernetes-and-minikube

Comment: @IvanDugalic i readed that doc as well, actually my yaml file based on that, still not working. trying to figure out how to do it

Comment: @pulp_fiction can you list your pods and services `kubectl get pods,svc` just to make sure that everything is up and running

Comment: @A_Suh do you see any fail in my config files ?

Answer (score 1):

your YAML is somehow mixed. If I understood you correctly, you have three services:

- command-service
- query-service
- axonserver

Your setup should be configured in a way that `command-service` and `query-service` expose their ports, but both use ports exposed by `axonserver`. Here is my attempt for your YAML:

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 kind: StatefulSet
 metadata:
   name: axonserver
   labels:
     app: axonserver
 spec:
   serviceName: axonserver
   replicas: 1
   selector:
     matchLabels:
       app: axonserver
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: axonserver
     spec:
       containers:
         - name: axonserver
           image: axoniq/axonserver
           imagePullPolicy: Always
         - name: grpc
           containerPort: 8124
           protocol: TCP
         - name: gui
           containerPort: 8024
           protocol: TCP
```

The ports your defined in:

```
       ports:
         - name: command-srv
           containerPort: 8081
           protocol: TCP
         - name: query-srv
           containerPort: 8082
           protocol: TCP
```

are not ports of Axon Server, but of your `command-service` and `query-service` and should be exposed in those containers.

Kind regards,

Simon

Comment: thank you, exactly i'm trying to do that. but somehow when log command or query and then i see still say: Connecting to AxonServer node axonserver:8124 failed: UNAVAILABLE: Unable to resolve host axonserver

Comment: Please post your yaml again for all three services

Comment: sorry for late respond, was away from pc. added my other config file too.